# Custom component undefined in React Native

Tags: react-native

I create a custom component called SimpleButton in a javascript file:

```
import React, {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class SimpleButton extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Simple Button</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Then I import it to index javascript file:

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import SimpleButton from './App/Components/SimpleButton';

class ReactNotes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SimpleButton/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNotes', () => ReactNotes);
```

Finally, run it on a Android device, it throws " ***Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined*** " error. The error leads to SimpleButton class declaration code line ('export default class SimpleButton extends React.Component'.

I currently use the latest version of React Native. I've searched some solutions but not works. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `import React from react-native` , which is not actually present within react-native. You should `import React from react` itself - instead. I've fixed the SimpleButton class below.

```
import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import React from 'react';

export default class Test extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Simple Button</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You could also just add the following -> `import {Component} from 'react';` and then simply use this feature as `export default class Test extends Component{...`,

( note this line replaces the `import React from 'react'`solution i mentioned before )

Hope this helps

Comment: You should implement this fix within both files by the way

Comment: I add " import React from 'react'; " and it's works now. Thank you very much!