# How to properly implement custom components in React Native in their own file?

Tags: react-native

I've moved my code of a custom React Native component to it's own file such as this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class MyButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: "#008000"}}>Foo Bar</Text>
        );
    };
};
```

In `App.js` I can refer to that file that contains that code. The framework does not complain:

`import { MyButton } from "./MyButton";`

But as soon as I include `MyButton` in the App rendering function I receive the following error:

*Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*

The rest of the error message is completely useless.

I did some searches on the web to learn what could have caused that error. But none of all hints I found seemed to be related to my case here. For example I use `import React from 'react';` which *is* advised by some answers even here on stack overflow, but still this doesn't work. (See: [Custom component undefined in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294097/custom-component-undefined-in-react-native))

If I move the code to `App.js` everything works fine. If I move it to another file things don't work. What do I need to change in that file in order to successfully have a component in that file? And include that in similar way as those native components in my `App.js`?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import statement is incorrect.

```js
import { MyButton } from "./MyButton";
```

This import statement imports a **named** export called `MyButton` from the `./MyButton` module. However, in your `MyButton` file you are **default** exporting the `MyButton` component. What you want to do is:

```js
import MyButton from "./MyButton";
```

which imports whatever is exported by default from the module, in this case the `MyButton` component.